# Where can I find the reference of Lord Ayyappa?

Tags: reference-request, ayyappa

I have seen a cartoon movie about lord Ayyappa. It shows that he is the son of Mohini (Vishnu took the form of Mohini) and Lord Siva. If I am not wrong, it also shows that after the death of Mahishashura, his sister Mahishi did penance and got the boon that no one born out of a woman's womb could kill her. So Vishnu took the form of Mohini. I guess, it must be in some Purana. In which Purana we can get the reference of Lord Ayyappa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The birth story of Ayyappa or Dharma Shasta is described in Lalitopakhyana of Brahmanda Purana -

1. Lord Shiva was enchanted by Mohini -

On seeing that lady engaged in playing with her ball with the jewels (jewelled ornaments like bangles etc) swinging to and fro, Īśvara (Śiva) immediately left Umā and ran after that lady.

2. The union of Shiva and mohini -

Seizing her once again, Īśa who was completely under the influence of the god of Love embraced her impetuously.

3. Birth of Shasta -

Mahāśāstā, the lord of great strength, was born therefrom. He was capable of dispelling the arrogance of many crores of leading Daityas.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya/d/doc362945.html

Comment: Mahasasta is another name of Ayyappa?

Comment: @Amritendu Mukhopadhyay- Yes.

Comment: I don't think there is any reference to say Ayyappa is Mahasasta. Ayyappa is a recent extension.

Comment: @Kanthri- Shasta is another name for Ayyappa. He is called as both Dharma Shasta and Maha Shasta. There are prayers about Ayyappa in which is called as Mahashasta.

Comment: Which scriptures say that ayyappa is Shasta?

Comment: @Kanthri - Sabarimala Sthala Purana and Bhutanatha Upakhyana.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this link](http://swatantramag.com/sabarimala-pilgrimage-who-is-stationed-at-erumeli-vapura-and-vavar/), ***brahmAnDapurANa*** has ***bhutanatha upakhyana*** which provides story of shastha :

[image]

English translation of book is found on [this link](https://srivedabooks.myinstamojo.com/product/225512/sri-butanatha-upakhyana-english/) & [this link](https://www.lazada.com.my/products/sri-bhutanatha-upakhyana-story-of-sabarimala-sastha-ayyapan-english-book-i2361674463-s10132309979.html?spm=a2o4k.tm80167375.9198521550.1.8812Og1nOg1nVC.8812Og1nOg1nVC&priceCompare=skuId%3A10132309979%3Bsource%3Alazada-om%3Bsn%3Aebea85c3-292d-4358-b4bd-1c2aaca02f5b%3BoriginPrice%3A7000%3BvoucherPrice%3A7000%3Btimestamp%3A1683641428986) with table of contents as below:

[image]

Story of shasta is also mentioned in shivarahasya in the shankara SamhitA of skandapurana whose translation is not available online but sanskrit version is available here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54258/21696

Comment: Hi sir, i had a doubt. I have heard sometimes that Poorna-Puskala mentioned in Sankara Samhita, but is it true?

Comment: Sir, I haven't read the entire chapter about shasta in skanda purana. If I find will post back. You may also go through the story in the link to find out

Comment: I recently found about Poorna-Puskala at 32th chapter of Upadesha Khanda of Sankara Samhita.

Comment: great ! will go through